# Uncheck the checked Checkbox if form submission is not completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a checkbox which once checked opens a popup window with form for file upload and text field. I want the checked checkbox to be unchecked if the form submission is not completed.

Pop up code is here

```
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "chk1" id = "chk1" onclick = "newPage('http://www.yourDomain/yourPopUpPage.html')">
```

Comment: please include all relevant code to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#chk1').prop('checked', false);
```

It will uncheck your checkbox. Use this code in the block where you are checking whether your form is submitted or not.